# How to insert records based on the number. For example If the code is 2 then it should insert two records into the target table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE main_tab 
(
    seq_id      NUMBER(10),
    e_id        NUMBER(10),
    code        NUMBER(10),
    active_flg  NUMBER(1),
    CONSTRAINT pk_main_tab PRIMARY KEY(seq_id)
);

INSERT INTO main_tab VALUES(1,11,3,1);
INSERT INTO main_tab VALUES(2,22,2,1);

CREATE SEQUENCE transact_tab_sq;

CREATE TABLE transact_tab 
(
    seq_id NUMBER(10) DEFAULT transact_tab_Sq.NEXTVAL,
    e_id NUMBER(10),
    code        NUMBER(10),
    start_date  DATE,
    end_date    DATE,
    active_flg NUMBER(1),
    CONSTRAINT pk_transact_tab PRIMARY KEY(seq_id)
);

COMMIT;
```

Tool used: SQL Developer (18c)

I want to insert rows into the `transact_tab` table from `main_tab` table. Let's say for `e_id = 11` whose `code` is 3 so in the `transact_tab` table there would be 4 records with the code 0,1, 2 and 3 and the `start_date` column for the code 3 will be today's date and from the code 0 - 2 `start_date` and `end_date` column will have today's date.

Similarly, for the `e_id` 22 which has `code` as 2 then there would be 3 records inserted into the `transact_tab` with the code 0,1, and 2 and for the `code` 2 `start_date` would be today's date and for the remaining code i.e 1 `start_date` and `end_date` both column should be today's date

Expected output:

```
+--------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+
| seq_id | e_id | code | start_Date | end_date | active_flg |
+--------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+
|      1 |   11 |    0 | 31-03-22   | 31-03-22 |          1 |
|      2 |   11 |    1 | 31-03-22   | 31-03-22 |          1 |
|      3 |   11 |    2 | 31-03-22   | 31-03-22 |          1 |
|      4 |   11 |    3 | 31-03-22   |          |          1 |
|      5 |   22 |    0 | 31-03-22   | 31-03-22 |          1 |
|      6 |   22 |    1 | 31-03-22   | 31-03-22 |          1 |
|      7 |   22 |    2 | 31-03-22   |          |          1 |
+--------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+
```

My Attempt:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
lv_count NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
SELECT code INTO lv_count FROM main_tab;
IF lv_count > 1 THEN
    FOR i IN(SELECT * FROM main_tab)
    LOOP
    INSERT INTO transact_tab VALUES(seq_id,e_id,code,start_date,end_date,active_flag)
    SELECT transact_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,e_id,code,sysdate,sysdate,active_flg FROM main_tab;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I am not sure how to fetch the code from the table and insert the records based on that

Comment: You have tagged your request `plsql`. So, do you want a PL/SQL solution? I.e. are you looking for a stored procedure to do this? Or is this a mistake and you only want SQL? Both is possible. In PL/SQL you could use a loop; in SQL you would use a recursive query. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes looking for stored procedure solution

Comment: Then please show us how far you have got. Where is the problem in your stored procedure? What is not working for you?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes I was trying using anonymous block but got stuck in fetching the code. I have added my attempt in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two loops: one for the rows in the main table, then one for each entry to be made for the row.

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM main_tab) LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. rec.code LOOP
      INSERT INTO transact_tab
        (e_id, code, start_date, end_date, active_flag)
      VALUES 
        (rec.e_id, i, TRUNC(SYSDATE), CASE WHEN rec.code <> i THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE), rec.active_flag);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

And you may or may not want to put the `COMMIT` somewhere inside the PL/SQL block.

Comment: I have one doubt for the same question. Suppose tomorrow 1-04-22 for the same e_id i.e 11 code 5 is present then I need not to disturb the existing record rather I will insert only the missing code i.e 4 and 5 and I will update the end_date of code 3 to tomorrow's date i.e 1-04-22 and for the code 4 and 5 logic remains the same for start_date and end_date which you have implemented. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. There are several options. One of them is to use `MERGE` instead of `INSERT` to write the row (update, if end_date is null; insert if row does not yet exist). You should have a unique constraint on (e_id, code) anyway, so you can also try to insert first and catch the exception.

Comment: But can I use FOR LOOP inside MERGE??

Comment: No, you replace the insert of one row with a merge for one row.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it in pl/sql

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM main_tab) LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. r.code LOOP
      INSERT INTO transact_tab (e_id, code,start_date, end_date,active_flg)
        VALUES (r.e_id, i, SYSDATE, CASE WHEN i = r.code THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END, r.active_flg);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

update based on comments:
*I have one doubt for the same question. Suppose tomorrow 1-04-22 for the same e_id i.e 11 code 5 is present then I need not to disturb the existing record rather I will insert only the missing code i.e 4 and 5 and I will update the end_date of code 3 to tomorrow's date i.e 1-04-22 and for the code 4 and 5 logic remains the same for start_date and end_date which you have implemented. Is this possible?*

```
DECLARE 
  l_transact_row transact_tab%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM main_tab) LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. r.code LOOP
      BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO l_transact_row 
          FROM transact_tab
         WHERE e_id = r.e_id AND code = i; 
        IF l_transact_row.end_date IS NULL AND i <> r.code THEN
          UPDATE transact_tab SET end_date = SYSDATE WHERE e_id = r.e_id AND code = i;
        END IF;
      EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO transact_tab (e_id, code,start_date, end_date,active_flg)
          VALUES (r.e_id, i, SYSDATE, CASE WHEN i = r.code THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END, r.active_flg);  
      END ;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I have one doubt for the same question. Suppose tomorrow 1-04-22 for the same ```e_id```  i.e 11 code 5 is present then I need not to disturb the existing record rather I will insert only the missing code i.e 4 and 5 and I will update the ```end_date``` of code 3 to tomorrow's date i.e 1-04-22 and for the code 4 and 5 logic remains the same for start_date and end_date which you have implemented. Is this possible?

Comment: Then you need to change the logic. Instead of inserting check if the row exists and if the end date is null. Then decide if you need to (1) do nothing (2) update the end date (3) add additional rows

Comment: It seems to be complex to me. Do I have to CASE here

Comment: Can you please update the code based on this requirement